# CMS Preview without styles when using custom theme

Tags: cms, theme, ee-1.13

I use magento EE 1.13.1.0 with custom theme which is set in System->Configuration->Design->Default.

The issue appears when we use Magento CMS Preview. It is displayed without custom theme styles, because by default magento preview use `base/default` theme.

If I edit Design tab of CMS Page and set `Custom Theme` attribute to some custom theme everything will work. But not by default.

Had someone this issue before? Maybe I missed some configuration?

Anyway to fix this issue I created observer and attached it to `cms_page_render` event to check if `Custom Theme` attribute of CMS page is set. If not, then use **real** default theme:

```
public function setDefaultThemeForCmsPreview(Varien_Event_Observer $oObserver)
{
    $oRequest = $oObserver->getControllerAction()->getRequest();
    if (
        $oRequest->getControllerName() == 'cms_page_revision' && 
        $oRequest->getActionName() == 'drop'
    ) {
        $oCmsPage = $oObserver->getPage();
        if ($oCmsPage->getCustomTheme()) {
            list($sPackage, $sTheme) = explode('/', $oCmsPage->getCustomTheme());
        } else {
            $sPackage = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/package/name');
            $sTheme   = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/theme/default');
        }
        Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package')
            ->setPackageName($sPackage)
            ->setTheme($sTheme);
    }
}
```

Comment: Using EE, you have paid support with Varien. Ask them about this, could be a bug that they will fix for you.

Comment: For the record I put the above Observer into place and it appears to be working well until a fix can be supplied by Magento

Comment: You may want to post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

I have come across this issue in Magento Enterprise 1.12.x - it does seem to be a Magento bug that has not been looked at. I believe my fix was to edit the AdminHTML however I believe your solution is more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem i got,
for that i Just copied "styles.css" and paste it to the "\skin\frontend\base\default\css" folder, then problem solved.

The css file not exist there, so the problem occured. May be this is the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But moving styles from your current theme to `base\default\` is not good fix of the problem. First of all, this is code duplication(you will need to support two files if you need to make changes to styles). The second negative point is that if you will change the theme, your problem will appear again.

Comment: I think, The problem caused because of style-sheet missing so i just copied CE default theme css(styles.css) to here.  its work fine. Even i have change the theme its working fine. I not suggest this is the solution, this is a bug in EE.